Not able to configure DataSync in azure sql
Trying to configure DataSync for Azure sql db with on premises SQLServer DB. Got this error.The sync database specified (sqlserver1\sql-syncmeta-prod-east-001) does not match the existing sync database (sqlserver2\sql-syncmeta-prod). Only one sync database is allowed per region per subscription. Please try again with the correct sync database name. any solution for this error.

You are mentioning you have the Hub database and the member (SQL Server database) but there needs to exist a 3rd database the Sync Metadata Database. The Sync Metadata Database contains the metadata and log for Data Sync, and Microsoft recommends creating a new, empty database for use as the Sync Metadata Database. Data Sync creates tables in this database and runs a frequent workload. Azure only supports one Sync Metadata Database per region and subscription. If you already have created one please move the database to the same subscription and region as the hub database.

